# (MAC OS) mksdcard: Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Mac OS 10.15.4

Android Studio 4.1.1

Latest android sdk tools: 30.0.3, but others installed as well (29.0.3, 26.0.2).

Running command on terminal, as [the example from Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/mksdcard)

```
Eduardos-MacBook-Pro:tools eduardo$ mksdcard -l mySdCard 1024M mySdCardFile.img
-bash: /Users/eduardo/Library/Android/sdk/tools/mksdcard: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this `Bad CPU type in executable`? Other suggestions only point to Linux or Windows.

My ultimate goal is to mount an SD card to the emulator. Any other way to do it will work too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try running the command in `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/` instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes it works thanks. I tried it on Mac m1